# read pdf from url to memory omitting saving file to local file

Tags: python, pdf

I have a problem with omitting saving file to a local file. My problem is how to pass directly the url content to the pdfplumber module. My code is as follows

```
from pathlib import Path
import urllib3
import pdfplumber

def read_pdf(url: str) -> str:
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    temp = Path('temp.pdf')
    temp.write_bytes(http.request("GET", url).data)
    with pdfplumber.open(temp) as pdf:
        text = pdf.pages[0].extract_text()
    temp.unlink()
    return text

text = read_pdf('https://sample.com/test.pdf')
```

It works but I would like to avoid saving file to local but do it in the RAM only.
I have tried io.BytesIO but it doesn't work

Comment: Which error do you experience with `io.BytesIO()`?

Comment: Try this: `import io; ... ; temp = io.BytesIO(); temp.write(http.request("GET" ,url).data); temp.seek(0); with...`

Comment: bytes, str or os.Path-like expected received _io.BytesIO

Comment: I see, that's because we need to pass folder, not file to `pdfplumber.open`

Comment: If it works this way, you would need to write the file on the hard drive. But you may do it clearer, too: use `tempfile` module. `import tempfile; ... ; with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp:`

Comment: I forgot about `pdfplumber.load`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, which uses `io.BytesIO()` instead of creating any files on the hard drive.
Note that `pdfplumber.load(...)` is used instead of `pdfplumber.open(...)`.

```
import urllib3
import pdfplumber
import io


def read_pdf(url: str) -> str:
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    temp = io.BytesIO()
    temp.write(http.request("GET", url).data)
    with pdfplumber.load(temp) as pdf:
        text = pdf.pages[0].extract_text()
    return text

text = read_pdf('https://sample.com/test.pdf')
```

Comment: @MarekKrzemiński I was very glad to help you :)

Answer (score 4):

Unlike previous suggestion, you should use `pdfplumber.open` instead of `pdfplumber.load`! [The link](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) for the repo of pdfplumber.

> Warning: pdfplumber.load is deprecated.Please use pdfplumber.open
> (with same arguments) instead.

Hence, the below code extracts entire pages rather than the first page in addition to using `pdfplumber.open` method.

```
import urllib3
import pdfplumber
import io


def extract_pdf_by_url(url):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    temp = io.BytesIO()
    temp.write(http.request("GET", url).data)
    all_text = ''
    with pdfplumber.open(temp) as pdf:
        for pdf_page in pdf.pages:
            single_page_text = pdf_page.extract_text()
            all_text = all_text + '\n' + single_page_text
    return all_text

url  = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/stable/examples/pdfs/background-checks.pdf'
text = extract_pdf_by_url(url)
print(text)
```